# pyrebase installation using pipenv failing

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm facing a serious problem when it comes to generating pipfile. lock. As I was trying to update the package list using the pipenv lock command I kept getting the following error message, The issue started appearing after I tried running `pipenv install pyrebase`:

```
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches requests==2.11.1,==2.23.0
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:
```

After trying the straight forward fixes like clearing the cache and try to install using the --pre suffix, I decided to update pipenv and that is when I started getting the error you see below, literally after almost every single command.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/users/abdul/anaconda3/envs/semsar-flask-env/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 807, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/users/abdul/anaconda3/envs/semsar-flask-env/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 794, in main
    from pipenv.vendor.vistir.misc import replace_with_text_stream
ImportError: cannot import name 'replace_with_text_stream'
```

Here's my pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
gunicorn = "==20.0.4"
appdirs = "==1.4.3"
bcrypt = "==3.1.7"
beautifulsoup4 = "==4.8.2"
bs4 = "==0.0.1"
certifi = "==2019.11.28"
cffi = "==1.14.0"
chardet = "==3.0.4"
click = "==7.1.1"
dataclasses = "==0.7"
decorator = "==4.4.2"
distlib = "==0.3.0"
filelock = "==3.0.12"
flask = "==1.1.1"
flask-admin = "==1.5.5"
flask-bcrypt = "==0.7.1"
flask-login = "==0.5.0"
flask-msearch = "==0.2.6"
flask-sqlalchemy = "==2.4.1"
flask-wtf = "==0.14.3"
idna = "==2.9"
importlib-metadata = "==1.5.0"
importlib-resources = "==1.3.1"
itsdangerous = "==1.1.0"
jinja2 = "==2.11.1"
kiwisolver = "==1.1.0"
matplotlib = "==3.2.0"
numpy = "==1.18.1"
pipenv = "==2018.11.26"
pycparser = "==2.20"
pyparsing = "==2.4.6"
python-dateutil = "==2.8.1"
six = "==1.14.0"
soupsieve = "==2.0"
sqlalchemy = "==1.3.15"
sqlalchemy-searchable = "==1.1.0"
sqlalchemy-utils = "==0.36.1"
urllib3 = "==1.25.8"
validators = "==0.14.2"
virtualenv = "==20.0.10"
virtualenv-clone = "==0.5.3"
whoosh = "==2.7.4"
wincertstore = "==0.2"
wtforms = "==2.2.1"
zipp = "==3.1.0"
Cycler = "==0.10.0"
import_string = "==0.1.0"
MarkupSafe = "==1.1.1"
Pillow = "==7.0.0"
Werkzeug = "==0.16.1"
psycopg2 = "*"
flask-babel = "*"
flask-migrate = "*"
flask-mail = "*"
flask-script = "*"
pyrebase = "*"
firebase-admin = "*"
requests = "==2.24.0"
```

is there a way to manually add pyrebase to the pipfile.lock, or simply a workaround to this problem?

Comment: Had a similar issue when installing pyrebase. It seems related to the requests library. Did you find a sollution without involving skipping the lock file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem stated above by bypassing pipfile.lock altogether through the following solution which forces Heroku to download the dependencies listed in `requirements.txt`.

I found the solution on GitHub:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/704#issuecomment-401533164